# PROLOG: calculating the quiz average, dropping the lowest score

Tags: prolog

**using Prolog**, calculate the quiz average (the lowest quiz should be dropped)

for example, if the quiz grades are 60,70,80,90,100, the average will be 85 (including the drop)

*given this statement to edit, where the ID is the way that the student is identified:*
**quiz_avg(ID,Average):-fail.**

*the quiz_avg method will be tested by results in the format:* "quizzes(j0105,80,70,20,99,100)"
where the first value is the student ID and the values following are the quiz scores of said student

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried? What's worked and what hasn't? Where are you stuck?

Comment: okay so I know that I could approach this by using a helper function to find the lowest score in the given list, and then removing that value from the quiz scores. And then, I would find the average of the remaining quiz scores, having taken out the lowest grade with the helper function. But I genuinely don't know how to approach it syntactically. I guess I'm looking for like a pseudocode hint to get me started?

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry, I'm kind of really desperate for a solution haha

Answer (score 0):

./src/parts/game.prolog

```
:- [library(clpfd)] .

%! game(GRADEs,AVERAGE)
%
% Drop the poorest quiz grade from the list of quiz grades `GRADEs`
% then calculate the `AVERAGE` of the remaining quiz grades .

game(GRADEs0,AVERAGE)
:-
smallest(GRADEs0,SMALLEST0) ,
select(SMALLEST0,GRADEs0,GRADEs1) ,
average(GRADEs1,AVERAGE)
.

/*

?- game([1,2,3,4],AVERAGE) .
AVERAGE = 3 ;
false .

?- game([1,2,3],AVERAGE) .
AVERAGE = 2.5 ;
false .

?- game([2,3],AVERAGE) .
AVERAGE = 3 ;
false .

?- game([],AVERAGE) .
false .

*/
```

./src/parts/smallest.prolog

```
%! smallest(Xs0,SMALLEST)
%
% `SMALLEST` is the smallest number in the list of numbers `Xs0` .

smallest([X0|Xs0],SMALLEST)
:-
smallest(Xs0,X0,SMALLEST)
.

smallest([],SMALLEST,SMALLEST) .

smallest([X0|Xs0],SMALLEST0,SMALLEST)
:-
SMALLEST1 #= min(X0,SMALLEST0) ,
smallest(Xs0,SMALLEST1,SMALLEST)
.

/*

?- smallest([1,2,3],SMALLEST) .
SMALLEST = 1 .

?- smallest([3,2,1],SMALLEST) .
SMALLEST = 1 .

?- smallest([3,1,2],SMALLEST) .
SMALLEST = 1 .

?- smallest([],SMALLEST) .
false .

*/
```

./src/parts/select.prolog

```
%! select(X0,Ys0,Zs) .
%
% `Zs` is `Ys0` without `X0` in it .

select(X0,[X0|Ys],Ys) .

select(X0,[Y0|Ys0],[Y0|Zs]) :- select(X0,Ys0,Zs) .

/*

?- select(1,[1,2,3],Zs) .
Zs = [2, 3] ;
false .

?- select(1,[3,2,1],Zs) .
Zs = [3, 2] ;
false .

?- select(1,[3,2,1,1],Zs) .
Zs = [3, 2, 1] ;
Zs = [3, 2, 1] ;
false .

?- select(1,[3,3],Zs) .
false .

?- select(1,[],Zs) .
false .

*/
```

./src/parts/average.prolog

```
%! average(Xs0,AVERAGE)
%
% `AVERAGE` is the average of the numbers in list `Xs0` .

average(Xs0,AVERAGE)
:-
lists:length(Xs0,LENGTH) ,
total(Xs0,TOTAL) ,
AVERAGE is TOTAL / LENGTH
.

/*

?- average([1,2,3],AVERAGE) .
AVERAGE = 2 .

?- average([1,2,3,4],AVERAGE) .
AVERAGE = 2.5 .

?- average([0],AVERAGE) .
AVERAGE = 0 .

?- average([],AVERAGE) .
false .

*/
```

./src/parts/total.prolog

```
%! total(Xs0,TOTAL)
%
%
% `TOTAL` is the sum of the numbers in list `Xs0` .

total([X0|Xs0],TOTAL)
:-
total(Xs0,X0,TOTAL)
.

total([],TOTAL,TOTAL) .

total([X0|Xs0],TOTAL0,TOTAL)
:-
TOTAL1 #= TOTAL0 + X0 ,
total(Xs0,TOTAL1,TOTAL)
.

/*

?- total([1,2,3],TOTAL) .
TOTAL = 6 .

?- total([2,2,3],TOTAL) .
TOTAL = 7 .

?- total([2],TOTAL) .
TOTAL = 2 .

?- total([],TOTAL) .
false .

*/
```

Comment: The total of nothing should be zero, no?